# Can you set Flutter Keys for widgets after the tree has been built?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I've been doing research into flutter keys and as far as I can see there's no way for me to ensure that the widget keys remain the same across debug builds if a key was not assigned at construction of that widget.

I'm looking for any resources about manipulating the widget tree by assigning keys to it or rebuilding an element and providing it with a new key.

The goal is to have an overlay on the screen, you tap on a widget item, Give it a name and the next time I run the app (debug mode only) it should have that name as the key.

I don't know if this is possible, but if anyone has some experience with the widget tree I would appreciate any guidance on it. I can access the tree through

```dart
WidgetsBinding.instance?.renderViewElement
```

And traverse through that. But is there any way I can do one of the following:

- Assign a widget key dynamically to a widget in the element tree
- Write my own widget tree builder / element tree builder (I would copy existing flutter one and make slight modifications)

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Why don't you just rebuild the widget with the new key?

Comment: @intraector That means I still have to go to every widget in every view for every code base and add a key. I'm trying to avoid that. It's very time consuming. And we have to do it for many code bases, that we didn't write. With thousands of widgets.

Comment: Ah, I see. Unfortunately, this is not possible. The only option I have in mind - full text search and replace, adding a key to every constructor. But this is dangerous and in some cases impossible to perform.

Comment: @intraector I appreciate that comment. I did not think of a tool "outside" of flutter to help us do that.